# Is it possible to create an engine yard instance without a database?

Tags: engineyard

I use MongoDB and don't need the normal Mysql/Postgres they seem to require you to choose from. Is it possible to deploy an engine yard cluster without a database? If you select more than two instances for the cluster it seems to REQUIRE a dedicated database instance.

Comment: Welcome to engine yard support...  Just kidding.  This is actually not a programming question and will likely be closed.

Comment: Ok I'm fine asking it elsewhere... There are other engine yard questions on here so I thought it might be ok.

Comment: Short answer: No. Being able to have web instances without db instances is coming (as is in house MongoDB support), but for now you'll need to waste money on the smallest db instance selectable.

Comment: Great thanks michael, that's all I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

As Zach mentions, this is correct.  We now have an option for database-less environments.  See this article for more info on how to get it for your account.

http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2012/announcing-database-less-env/